# recursive file copying into subdirectory

Tags: python

I need to copy all the files and folders to the current folder to a subdirectory. What would be the best way to do so? I tried the following snippet but it fails as it fails if the destination directory already exists.

```
def copy(d=os.path.curdir):
    dest = "t"
    for i in os.listdir(d):
        if os.path.isdir(i):
            shutil.copytree(i, dest)
        else:
            shutil.copy(i, dest)
```

I have the feeling that the same task can be done in a better and easier manner. How do i do it?

Comment: Is the destination subfolder empty when you start copying?

Comment: The snippet is completely bugly. 1) What is the reason to `copytree` on subdirs and not on the root? 2) `d`, `dest` aren't used.

Comment: @khachik sorry, had typed in a hurry. [2] taken care of.

Comment: @khachik [1] I felt that copying the contents of directory/ to directory/inner_directory would cause a problem as inner_directory would try to copy itself. An OSError, I guessed.

Comment: @Sven yes, initially the subfolder to which I am trying to copy to would be empty.

Comment: @zubin71 in that case `shutil.copytree(os.path.join(i), os.path.join(dest, i)`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would never do it on python, but the following solution came to mind. It doesn't look simple, but it should work  and can be simplified (haven't checked, sorry, no access to the computer now):

```
def copyDirectoryTree(directory, destination, preserveSymlinks=True):
  for entry in os.listdir(directory):
    entryPath = os.path.join(directory, entry)
    if os.path.isdir(entryPath):
      entrydest = os.path.join(destination, entry)
      if os.path.exists(entrydest):
        if not os.path.isdir(entrydest):
          raise IOError("Failed to copy thee, the destination for the `" + entryPath + "' directory exists and is not a directory")
        copyDirectoryTree(entrypath, entrydest, preserveSymlinks)
      else:
        shutil.copytree(entrypath, entrydest, preserveSymlinks)
    else: #symlinks and files
      if preserveSymlinks:
        shutil.copy(entryPath, directory)
      else:
        shutil.copy(os.path.realpath(entryPath), directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the code in http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html, then tweak it a little (e.g. try: around os.makedirs(dst)).

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping to avoid this, but guess there is no other way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To extend mamnun's answer,

If you want to use the direct call to the os, I'd advise using cp -r since you seem to want a recursive copy for directories.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use python? Because shutil functions cannot copy all file metadata and group permissions. Why don't you try built-in OS commands like `cp` in linux and `xcopy` in windows?

You can even try to run these commands from python

```
import os

os.system("cp file1 file2")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Um, is using os.system a good practice? Assuming that I would resort to using this, I would need some sort of bash pipeing; it would make the code platform dependent.

Comment: @khachik: for windows `xcopy` command could be used.  

@zubin71: Just another solution. And I think, `cp` and `xcopy` can do better job at copying files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of a recursive copy method for python, seems to work :)

```
def copy_all(fr, to, overwrite=True):
  fr = os.path.normpath(fr)
  to = os.path.normpath(to)

  if os.path.isdir(fr):
    if (not os.path.exists(to + os.path.basename(fr)) and not
    os.path.basename(fr) == os.path.basename(to)):
      to += "/" + os.path.basename(fr)
      mkdirs(to)
    for file in os.listdir(fr):
      copy_all(fr + "/" + file, to + "/")
  else: #symlink or file
    dest = to
    if os.path.isdir(to):
      dest += "/"
      dest += os.path.basename(fr)

    if overwrite and (os.path.exists(dest) or os.path.islink(dest)
      rm(dest)

    if os.path.isfile(fr):
      shutil.copy2(fr, dest)
    else: #has to be a symlink
      os.symlink(os.readlink(fr), dest)  


def mkdirs(path):                                                 
  if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.makedirs(path)


def rm(path):                                                     
  if os.path.isfile(path) or os.path.islink(path):
    os.remove(path)
  elif os.path.isdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
      fullpath = path+"/"+file
      os.rmdir(fullpath)
```